# Search and replace multiple values in a 2d array Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
 ID      Number
 ssk ,   0
 ssk ,   999999
 ssk ,   0
 oit ,   999999
 dnp ,   54
 dnp ,   2
 dnp ,   999999
```

Above is an example of a shortened version of the csv file I am reading from. My intention is to check if there is 0 in a given row, if so, replaces all appearances of the ID to an empty String. As well as only keeps the ID for the min value if not 0. How would my current program be changed to get the output wanted? I am open to any and all solutions, I have been working on this for many hours at my place of employment. Thank you.

wanted output

```
ID       Number
     ,   0
     ,   999999
     ,   0
oit  ,   999999
     ,   54
dnp  ,   2
     ,   999999
```

My current program is below:====================================================

```
        import java.io.*;
        import java.lang.reflect.Array;
        import java.util.*;

        public class ImapSync{

            public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
                FileReader fr = new FileReader("Sync report.csv");
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(fr);
                String[][] array = new String [101000][2];
                int i = 0;

                while(sc.hasNext()){
                    String line = sc.nextLine();
                    String field[] = line.split(",");
                    //          System.out.println(field[5]);
                    for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
                        //              System.out.println(field[5] + " " + i);
                        array[i][j] = field[j];
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                sc.close();
                Commands c = new Commands(array);

                c.changeArrayValues();
        //      c.print();
                c.arrayToFile();
            }




        }


    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.lang.reflect.Array;
    import java.util.Arrays;

    public class Commands {
        private String array[][];

        public Commands(String array[][]){
            this.array= array;
        }
        public void print(){
            for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++){         
                    if(j == 0)
                        System.out.printf("%-70s " , array[i][j]);
                    else
                        System.out.printf("%-20s ", array[i][j]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }

        public void arrayToFile() throws IOException{
            File f = new File("C:/Users/abc.csv");
            PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(f);

            for(int i = 0; i < 100981; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
                    p.print(array[i][j] + ",");
                }
                p.println();
            }
            p.close();
        }

        public void changeArrayValues(){
            int arrayPosition = 0;
            while(arrayPosition < 100981){
                if(Integer.parseInt(array[arrayPosition][1]) == 0){
                    String userID = array[arrayPosition][0];

                    for(int i = 0; i < 100981; i++){
                        if(array[i][0] == userID){
                            array[arrayPosition][0] = "";
                        }
                    }
                }
                arrayPosition++;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: And your question is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the existing 'changeArrayValues' method with following and let me know, whether it works for you:

```
public  void changeArrayValues(){
    int arrayPosition = 0;
    while(arrayPosition < array.length){
           if(array[arrayPosition][1] != null && Integer.parseInt(array[arrayPosition][1].trim()) == 0){
                String userID = array[arrayPosition][0].trim();
                for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
                    if(array[i][0] != null && array[i][0].trim().equals(userID)){
                        array[i][0] = "";
                    }
                }
            }else if (array[arrayPosition][0] != null && !array[arrayPosition][0].equals("")) {
                String userID2 = array[arrayPosition][0].trim();
                int min = Integer.parseInt(array[arrayPosition][1].trim());
                for (int j=0;j<array.length;j++){
                    if (array[j][0] != null && array[j][1] != null){
                        if(array[j][0].equals(userID2) && Integer.parseInt(array[j][1].trim()) < min){
                            min = Integer.parseInt(array[j][1].trim());
                            array[arrayPosition][0] = "";
                        } else if (array[j][0].equals(userID2) && Integer.parseInt(array[j][1].trim()) > min)
                            array[j][0] = "";
                    }
                }
         }

        arrayPosition++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I receive a null pointer on this line:                                                   if(array[j][0].equals(userID2) && Integer.parseInt(array[j][1]) < min){

Comment: I have handled the null values in the edited code above. Please try now and let me know, if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I realy can see about 200 ways to do this :)

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
String holdKey = "The most strange value you can get";
String[] splited = new String[2];
boolean zeroFound;

while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null) 
    list.add(ch);

for(int i=list.size()-1;i>=0;i--) {
    splited = list[i].split(",");

    if (!holdKey.equals(splited[0]) {          //checks key changes
      //previus item has to be updated, and previus is +1
      list[i+1] = (zeroFound?"   ":holdKey) + ", " + splited[1];     
      holdKey = splited[0];
    }

    //check if value is zero, after ofc.
    zeroFound |= "0".equals(trim(splited[1])); 

}

//Finally finish with the 1st item
 list[0] = (zeroFound?"   ":holdKey) + ", " + splited[1];
```

I didn't run the code so there might be some bugs... and I got annoyed becouse [tab] doesn't work in the editor...